# google sign in implementation in codeigniter google return response code with "/" in value which break the code

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-api-php-client, google-api-client

**this is my controller for google login . code does't work after google response code.**

```
   public function index(){
    // Include the google api php libraries
    require_once APPPATH.'libraries/google-api-php-client/vendor/autoload.php';

    // Google Project API Credentials
    $clientId = 'mentioned';
    $clientSecret = 'mentioned';
    $redirectUrl = base_url() . 'user_authentication/';


    // Google Client Configuration
        $gClient = new Google_Client();
        $gClient->addScope('email');
        $gClient->setApplicationName('REDBUD HOTELS');
        $gClient->setClientId($clientId);
        $gClient->setClientSecret($clientSecret);
        $gClient->setRedirectUri($redirectUrl);
        $google_oauthV2 = new Google_Service($gClient);
//GOOGLE response
        if (isset($_REQUEST['code'])) 
                  {
                    $gClient->authenticate($_REQUEST['code']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('token', $gClient->getAccessToken());
                    header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);    

                  }
 //check if $token us set 
        $token = $this->session->userdata('token');
        if (!empty($token)) 
            {
            $gClient->setAccessToken($token);
            }

        if ($gClient->getAccessToken())
            {
            $userProfile = $plus->userinfo->get();
            // Preparing data for database insertion
            $userData['oauth_provider'] = 'google';
            $userData['oauth_uid'] = $userProfile['id'];
            $userData['first_name'] = $userProfile['given_name'];
            $userData['last_name'] = $userProfile['family_name'];
            $userData['email'] = $userProfile['email'];
            $userData['gender'] = $userProfile['gender'];
            $userData['locale'] = $userProfile['locale'];
            $userData['profile_url'] = $userProfile['link'];
            $userData['picture_url'] = $userProfile['picture'];
            // Insert or update user data
            $userID = $this->user->checkUser($userData);
            if(!empty($userID))
            {
                $data['userData'] = $userData;
                $this->session->set_userdata('userData',$userData);
            } else 
            {
               $data['userData'] = array();
            }
        } else
         {
            $data['authUrl'] = $gClient->createAuthUrl();
         }
        $this->load->view('user_authentication/index',$data);
    }
```

**"response Code From Google user_authentication/?code=4/5wcPW5Yv6qNONOzeUz5gun4PtfuPTa6mPN9r97BDhGM# "**
please also tell me what should be better  `$plus->userinfo->get() or $google_oauthV2->userinfo->get();`

Answer (score 0):

google response code does have "/"

ex: `http://www.example.com/storage_integration/granted?code=4/oXKtlTyfmtzUBc5CjbafSpwItMz7itZMhM54VpKEbwI`

you can use `$_GET` instead of `$_REQUEST`

```
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
   // authenticate auth code here
}
```

Comment: i Tried this but because of codeigniter user friendly url this response from google gives an error

Comment: i was overthinking about the problem it was just google api update by just  replacing object new Google_Service($gClient);  with Google_Service_Oauth2($gClient); solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

By just replacing object new Google_Service($gClient); with Google_Service_Oauth2($gClient); solved the Error